# PFUser currentUser nil after app update

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I've updated my iOS app in the App Store and there seems to be a bug for users who install the update: their `PFUser currentUser` is returning `nil`.  Any idea why would this happen?

To add info, I'm enabling automatic users with this code in my `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`:

```
[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];
PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
[PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

So how come `[PFUser currentUser]` can be `nil?`

Comment: Have you figured out what caused that to occur?

Comment: I went back to a previous version of the parse sdk and the problem went away. But I don't remember the exact version I was using.

Comment: Okay thanks, that helped solve the issue