# PFUser currentUser returns nil after restarting app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift2, pfuser

I'm working on a swift iPhone application using Parse for the backend and when I restart the app the `currentUser` isn't recognized and returns nil redirecting to the login page.  Once I sign back in the user stays logged in until I stop the app.

```
if PFUser.currentUser() == nil {
  //return to the login page 
} else {
  // perform normal operations
}
```

I'm curious why this is happening since the only place I have `PFUser.logOut()` is in a logout function which is not on the initial view controller and only called when a button is pressed.  Thanks in advance for the help!

**EDIT**: This problem began occurring this morning.  The past 2 weeks I haven't had any issues regarding automatic login with parse.  So I don't know what I could have done to cause it.  The only code I changed between last night and this morning was trying to pass data from one view controller to a popoverViewController by adding delegates to my VC's but I have since deleted them and am still at a loss.

Comment: what do you mean by restarting the app?

Comment: Do you use Parse local datastore?

Comment: By restarting the app I mean killing it and any background processes and then opening it back up.  And no I'm not using the local datastore for anything.

Comment: I am not using the local datastore but it IS enabled

Comment: Sounds like you didnt set the currentUser on login.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up downloading the latest Parse SDK and it solved the problem.  Eddy from this post [PFUser currentUser nil after app update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28453415/pfuser-currentuser-nil-after-app-update?noredirect=1#comment52738594_28453415) also said reverting to a previous Parse SDK also solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should place this code in the **AppDelegate** into the method **applicationDidBecomeActive()**, something like the following:

```
 func applicationDidBecomeActive(application: UIApplication) 
 {

    if PFUser.currentUser() == nil{
        // show main screen

        var storyboard :UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var LoginScreen = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("loginShow") as! UIViewController
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(LoginScreen, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    else 
    {
        //show login screen
        var storyboard :UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        var MainScreenNavigation = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("TotalMainViewController") as! UIViewController
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().keyWindow?.rootViewController?.presentViewController(MainScreenNavigation, animated: false, completion: nil)

    }

}
```

Comment: It still returns nil for the user and segues to the login form page

Comment: did you login to app  before you shut it down?

Comment: Yes I did, I tried with two different accounts only to face the same result

Comment: what about your PFUser.Logout() is it working? you should try to reset your simulator also because this is weird

Comment: The PFUser.logOut() works perfectly.  Just restarted both my phone and simulator, we'll see what happens.